# WCF service method needs myClassRequest type instead of myClass

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf

I have a simple WCF service like the following

```
namespace FingerPrintWebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IIdentifyFingerPrint
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int IdentifyFinger(FingerPrint fingerPrint);
    }

    public class IdentifyFingerPrintService:IIdentifyFingerPrint
    {
        public int IdentifyFinger(FingerPrint fingerPrint)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class FingerPrint
    {
        [DataMember]
        public byte[] CurrentTemplate;

        [DataMember]
        public int CurrentTemplateSize;
    }
}
```

in which my method `IdentifyFinger` needs a parameter of type `FingerPrint`  and it returns `Int`.

The problem is when I want to use this service in my service client, it needs `FingerPrintRequest` type and it returns `FingerPrintRespond` type which are different from what I wrote

[image]

What is the problem? why I can't provide `FingerPrint` type as the parameter?

Comment: did you update all your references and rebuild the solution?

Comment: something somewhere is holding onto an old reference hence this issue.

Comment: Are you adding it as a Service Reference or WebService Reference? It looks like you are adding in the old style instead of Service Reference.

Answer (score 0):

- Go into your "Service References"
- Right click on the reference.
- Select "Configure Service Reference".
- Tick the red : [image]

If this fails, delete your reference and reimport it and make sure that box is not ticked.

Comment: No! it doesn't wok yet :( I followed your instruction

Comment: I see that you've rebuilt you're solution; however, did you clean your solution and then try reimporting? Also, have you rebooted your computer or closed your visual studio and reloaded it? Sometimes miscellaneous things happen.

Comment: Finally it works. I deleted my whole service project and recreate that. I also uncheck `Reuse types in referenced assemblies` in service configuration page. and it worked. thanks you all

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh If the answered helped you please mark it as correct. If no answer helped you not but you found an answer I suggest  answering your own question and marking it correct.